DO as an option on bond future
I was reading about the bond basis trade and there are a few things I don't really get.
1- When someone is long the basis it means you buy the CTD and short the bond future. The bond future price can be written as: $F = FP_{CTD}/CF_{CTD} - DO$ where $DO$ is the delivery option and $FP_{CTD}$ is the forward price of the CTD.  Hence being long the basis means being long the $DO$. Yet to enter this position you first need to pay: $FP_{CTD}$ and when you short you gain $F$ dollars. So to enter the position you pay: $F-FP_{CTD} = -DO$, so you loose money to enter the position? And then assuming that the CTD doesn't change then you have $DO \to 0$ and hence you just loose money since your are long the $DO$... What am I doing wrong here?
2- When you are long the basis you are long the delivery option. So you want high vol and to be close to the inflections points where the CTD can change. In that case the delivery option gets a lot of value and increase since there's a higher chance of CTD switch. In that case do you hold your long basis position to expect the CTD switch to happen and thus makes money? Or you directly make money by saying your long basis? (so you get money because you sell $DO$ which is high)
3- When you look at the payoff of a long basis at maturity, it's basically a call option with strike equal to the inflection point. So can you trade vol by being long the basis since it's the same as a call option? Can you quantify your vega and gamma on that long basis position? And finally are there arbitrage opportunities between the call and the long basis position?


The value of the delivery options is roughly the bnoc. 2. You make money when the delivery options grow in value and/or there is a switch, as the net basis of your issue will grow. 3. Whether the basis is a call or put or straddle depends on where the issue yield is vs the notional coupon. So at the moment most cheapest to deliver trades short duration

